# Registration station

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to come up with the English word for this place.
Place description: Someone is typing their name and select items that they borrow on a mounted device, to the wall or the floor. Then later, they return those items to the exact same place.

*Registration Station* I think is too long and difficult to say, so the shorter or more elegant, the better

Comment: Could trim it down to _registation_ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest “Lending Station”. What you are describing sounds like people are borrowing an item similar to a book at a library.

Answer (score 9):

I think that **kiosk** may be the best word. It originally referred to a small sheltered structure or hut, but has become more broadly defined as

> a small structure in a public area used for providing information or displaying advertisements, often incorporating an interactive display screen or screens.

Here is one of the top image results for "kiosk":

[image: Three ordering stations at a fast-food restaurant]

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted.  Even medical offices nowadays are setting up self-check-in kiosks.  Also Kohl's (clothing store) has kiosks where you can stand and make a catalog order if your size is out of stock.

Comment: Nice suggestion, I like it. Still feel that it may be too broad of a term though. What about those parking ticket machines where you get a ticket on your way in and insert the ticket on your way out? Except what I think of is not a parking ticket but things that you borrow and return back, and you do it on the same device. So it's both a checkin and checkout but also registers your name.

Answer (score 1):

This is how tool cribs work. You exchange your chit for a tool. In this case, it's an electronic chit. Some places take your id or driver's license.

I'd call it a loaner station, and I'm not the only one -
https://www.boatingsafety.com/store/viewproduct.aspx?id=14842788
[image]